# Removing hair particle to edit mesh

Tags: particles, weight-painting, texture-painting

I have been wondering if there is a way to remove the hair particle completely so I can edit the dog mesh without losing the texture. [image]

This is after editing the dog mesh while the hair is on. Texture paint got lost. Is it possible to modify texture or weight paint after having the hair particles on?

Comment: you can click the eye-icon next to each particle system to turn them off...just like in the Outliner :]

Comment: Yeah, but I want to delete the particle system not keep them on, because they wouldn't let me weight paint.

Comment: oh...if you want to delete the particle system, just click the Minus Sign next to the Eye-icon. hope it does the trick.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Though I figured out it wasn't the problem. I still have no idea why I can't weight paint to isolate the hairs to specific areas.